# Deciding on Limits of Integration Double Integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Compute the integral $$\iint_{\mathcal{D}} \ln(x) \, dA$$ where $\mathcal{D}$ is the region in the first quadrant which lies between the line $2x + 2y = 5$ and the hyperbola $xy = 1$, displayed in yellow below.

[image]

My issue is finding the limits of integration. Clearly, we have intersection of the curves in $x = \frac{1}{2}$ and $x = 2$, which are the limits in $x$. However, I'm not sure about the limits of $y$. We have from the two curves $y = \frac{1}{x}$ and $y = \frac{5}{2} - x$, and $y$ starts at $\frac{1}{2}$ and ends at 2, and varies as  $y = \frac{1}{x}$ or $y = \frac{5}{2} - x$ in between. Therefore, it seems to me that all of the following limits for $y$: $$0.5 < y < \frac{1}{x} \\\ \frac{1}{x} < y < 2 \\\ 0.5 < y < \frac{5}{2} - x \\\ \frac{5}{2} - x < y < 2 \\\ \frac{1}{x} < y < \frac{5}{2} - x \\\ \frac{5}{2} - x < y < \frac{1}{x} $$ could all be viable options. I don't understand why only one of these would be correct.

Any help with understanding how to find the limits of integration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just $$\int_{x=1/2}^2 \int_{y=1/x}^{5/2-x} \ln x \, dy \, dx.$$

The $x$-coordinates of the intersection points establish the limits of integration with respect to $x$, and then for a representative vertical slice at some point $x = x_0$, the lower boundary is the curve $y = 1/x$, so the lower limit is $y_L = 1/x_0$, and the upper boundary is the curve $y = 5/2 - x$, so the upper limit is $y_U = 5/2 - x_0$.  That is true for any $x \in [1/2, 2]$.  So for $x = x_0$, the interval of integration with respect to $y$ is $[1/x_0, 5/2 - x_0]$.

As a further exercise, what would the limits of integration be if the order of integration is reversed?  Hint:  take the $y$-coordinates of the intersection points as the limits of integration with respect to $y$, and write the interval of integration with respect to $x$ in terms of the boundary equations by expressing them as functions of $y$.